# How to make an app unclosable?

Tags: java, android

After a user opens my application I don't want them to be able to get out. So when they press the home or back button it doesn't let them exit the app. I know there are ways using a service to keep the app always running in the background, but I don't even want them to even exit.

Is this even possible, if so how? Without having to hack the kernel.

I know this sounds odd, but it is not for a commercial app, but for my lab, it will never be on GooglePlay. The tablets will be given to little kids and they will take a test on it, so I can't have them using youtube or anything else.

---

Related post: [Android, How to make the task of the app unclosable? Only closable by task killing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746875/android-how-to-make-the-task-of-the-app-unclosable-only-closable-by-task-killi)

The answer by [CommonWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) seems to indicate that kernel hacking is the only way, but is it?

Also I am using **Android L**.

Comment: Well it is for testing other software in my lab, not for putting it out on the market to annoy people.

Comment: If it's just for your lab, just *don't press the back button*.

Comment: I don't want to be smacking people's hands all day when they do that.

Comment: Again it won't be published.

Comment: I'd damn you in eternity, if I'd ever happen to use such an app...

Comment: You could always restart the tablet if it scares you so much.

Comment: Disabling the back button is incredibly easy (just override onBackPressed()), I think the home button is intentionally difficult to reconfigure though

Comment: It doesn't **scare** me. It makes me **angry**. I'd have to resort to `Manage Applications` and **exterminate** it from there. Then **uninstall** it and leave a **very bad comment** on the Play Store.

Comment: @RichardTingle true, I think it **forces** you back to the main screen on the device without any control, if pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no official support yet - there will be support with android L via the Task locking API

> The L Developer Preview introduces a new task locking API that lets
>   you temporarily restrict users from leaving your app or being
>   interrupted by notifications. This could be used, for example, if you
>   are developing an education app to support high stakes assessment
>   requirements on Android. Once your app activates this mode, users will
>   not be able to see notifications, access other apps, or return to the
>   Home screen, until your app exits the mode.

https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html

EDIT: as you said you use L this got obsolete - but I leave it here as a hint for others

said that - you are also able to get this kind of work without root today if you have to ( e.g. kiosk mode app on a certain hardware ). It is not simple - and no solution that works for all devices - but if you need it you can get it work with tricks like:
 - reacting on home-screen intent ( and setting it as default )
 - when you go to background - bring your self foreground again
 - ..

Comment: That's awesome I am using L! Forgot to mention.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein there are valid use cases for this

Comment: @J_Strauton great! you might then want to consider accepting the answer

Comment: @ligi ... for instance?

Answer (score 0):

It seems google has some thing called COSU for setting up single-purpose devices

> Android 5.0 Lollipop introduced two new ways to configure Android
>   devices for a single purpose:
>
> - With app pinning, the device user can temporarily pin specific apps to the screen.
> - With lock task mode, a user can’t escape the app and the Home and Recents buttons are hidden. Additionally, lock task mode gives the IT
>     administrator a more robust way to manage COSU devices, as discussed
>     below.

and

> As an IT administrator, you can configure Android 6.0 Marshmallow and
>   later devices as corporate-owned, single-use (COSU) devices. These are
>   Android devices used for a single purpose, such as digital signage,
>   ticket printing, point of sale, or inventory management. To use
>   Android devices as COSU devices, you need to develop Android apps that
>   your customers can manage.

[from here](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu)

and there is a [code lab for it here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cosu/index.html)

for earlier versions of android here i founded [How-To Create a Working Kiosk Mode in Android](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) which shows some hacks for disabling buttons and restarting the application after boot and lock. **note that most of these hacks, don't work on android 6 and later**