# Way(s) to make Android app only close-able by password?

Tags: android

For a POS system is there a way or ways to make an application harder to close? 
The desire is to have employees be able to use the device and the application, but not use other applications.

The implementation does not necessarily require a password. So far the answers I have seen on similar questions suggest this is not possible. Except in Lollipop per this question : [How to make an app unclosable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324810/how-to-make-an-app-unclosable)

Are there any options for older APIs?

Or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible as a feature of the API since the Android system is in control of what is executed or stopped. And that could mean that your app gets stopped for a number of reasons.

To achieve what you are asking for you will need to create your own distribution of the system. I have no experience of doing that but it basically means creating a rom and distribute it.

That would of course be an option if the device running the POS app is only used for that particular task.